# How to handle params conditions in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to apply multiple conditions for paraams, I have a below code:

```
if !params[:parametersSch].blank?

       @dynamicDegree = params[:parametersSch]
       @dynamicFrom = params[:ParametersFromSch]
       @dynamicTo = params[:ParametersToSch]
```

In the above code "parametersSch" is my text_field name, "ParametersFromSch" is a dropdown name that have years and "ParametersToSch" is also dropdown that also have years and the above code working fine that if params[:parametersSch] is not equal to blank then it puts values in vaiables, but when this condition is false means params[:parametersSch] is equal to blank then I puts empty string in a variables i.e below:

```
   @dynamicDegree = ''
   @dynamicFrom = ''
   @dynamicTo = ''
```

But its not working, Kindly suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if params.has_key?(:parametersSch) && params[:parametersSch].present?

   @dynamicDegree = params[:parametersSch]
   @dynamicFrom = params[:ParametersFromSch]
   @dynamicTo = params[:ParametersToSch]
else
   @dynamicDegree = nil
   @dynamicFrom = nil
   @dynamicTo = nil
end
```

Comment: but if params[:parametersSch] is not present then how do I put empty string into variables

Comment: you mean to say, you are not sending params[:parametersSch] some time.. if this is the case then use has_key?. if(params.has_key?(:parametersSch))